# Redirect all files in old domain directory to same files in root of new domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, directory, domain-name

I'm facing a change of domain and directory at the same time.

Using WHM, the account's old domain name was changed to the new domain name. The old domain name is now parked on top of the new domain name using cPanel.

Every file in www.olddomain.com/store should redirect to the same file in the root of www.newdomain.com.

For www and HTTPS I'm using this at the start of the .htaccess file and it works fine:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [E=HTTPS,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

To redirect files I'm using this that redirects everything to the root of the new domain, not the corresponding file name in the new domain (what I really need):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$
RewriteRule ^store/(.*)$ "https\:\/\/www\.newdomain\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

After numerous tests I think this should work, but it doesn't. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Also you can use a simple one liner Redirect instead of the **mod-rewrite**   .  `Redirect /store/ http://newdomain.com/`

Comment: Thanks. Shame on me. The old directory was still there! I renamed it and everything worked fine.